# Converting 13 band .tif images to RGB using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I have sentinel 2 images. Each image has 13 bands (bands are not individual images). I wanted to convert them to only RGB images and store them in a file to use for another purpose.

I have tried

```
raster - Conversion - PCT to RGB
```

But it does not work. this is the error:

```
 File "/usr/bin/pct2rgb.py", line 121, in 

 ct_size = ct.GetCount()

 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetCount'
```

is there a fix to this or any other methods to achieve converting multiband to rgb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't convert 13 band image into RGB but you can select 3 bands out of 13 and save them as RGB. I would do that with gdal_translate https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html.

Example that select bands 1, 10, and 13:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 1 -b 10 -b 13 input_sentinel_13_band.tif output_RGB.tif
```

Be aware that this as-simple-as-possible command yields a TIFF file that is most probably not optimal for QGIS. There are bunch of options for formatting TIFFs in https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html. Learning what they all mean will take some time but is certainly worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks. it works well. I was actually going to use gdal translate to use converting it to jpg but subselecting bands and doing the conversion saves a lot of work.